# How to choose handler while logging in python

Tags: python, logging, handler

I am working on a project with python  and I need to help about logging part. My logger have two handler(syslog and file log) and it send logs to both of them. Sometimes I need to send logs only one of them. How can I choose handler to be used? Thanks for help...

```
global my_Sysloghandler
global my_logger, my_log_handler

my_Sysloghandler=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler()
my_log_handler= logging.FileHandler('/var/log/{0}.log'.format(__project__))
my_log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))                                                                              
my_log_handler.setLevel(level)
my_logger= logging.getLogger('my_logger')
my_logger.addHandler(my_log_handler)
my_logger.addHandler(my_Sysloghandler)

my_logger.debug('This log is sent to both handler but I want to send it only my_logger')
```

Comment: Your code extract is incomplete. What is the value of `level`? Set the level of `my_log_handler` to `DEBUG` and the level of `my_Sysloghandler` to `INFO` and as a result everything logged as `DEBUG` will ONLY be logged to your `my_log_handler`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your choices are:

- Prioritize one over the other (i.e. SysLogHandler gets INFO messages or above, while FileHandler gets DEBUG or above)
- Use two different logger instances.

FWIW, the regular logging docs can be tough to read through.  Instead, take a look at the [Logging HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html) and [Logging Cookbook](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for something more easily digestible.